# Returning columns conditionally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've read quite a few questions and answers on using indexing with pandas in python, but I can't work out how to return columns conditionally. For instance, consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]], columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df)

   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0
```

How would I ask pandas to give me column names such that value in row zero and that column is 1? Anticipated output: `['b','c']`

How would I ask pandas to give me column names such that value in row zero and row one of that column is 1? Anticipated output: `['c']`

I'm comfortable using `.loc` to find all rows where specific conditions are true, but this is slightly different.

Comment: Do you mean  `df.columns[df.loc[0] == 1];df.columns[(df.loc[:1] == 1).all()]`?

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham! To make it a tiny bit more general, what if I switched rows 1 and 2 so that you couldn't slice it up in the way that you did in the second code snippet? Instead of `df.loc[:1]`, can I use `df.loc[[0,2]]`, or something like that?

Comment: You mean the first and third row?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- , i.e. I want columns in which the first and third rows have a one, even though there are no such rows in the example.

Comment: Using `df.columns[(df.loc[[0, 2]] == 1).all()]` would return `[]` using your current df

Comment: OK, perfect, then it's working! Thanks @PadraicCunningham. If you want to make it into an answer, I'll accept it with gratitude. Thanks for bringing my attention to using columns as the attribute.

Comment: no worries, you can add an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PadraicCunningham provided a solution in the comments. It was as simple as:

```
df.columns[df.loc[0] == 1]
```

If I want to select only columns that meet two (or more criteria), that can be listed in statements like the following:

```
df.columns[(df.loc[:1] == 1).all()]
df.columns[(df.loc[[0, 2]] == 1).all()]
```

The former returns columns in which all but the last row takes value 1. The latter returns columns in which the first and third row (labeled 0 and 2) take value 1. My error was trying to do this with `df.loc`.